# How to double expand a variable name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interpolation

Given an AngularJS template variables are automatically expanded by the framework when they are entered in the template.

Ex:

```
app.controller( "myCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.myVar = "Some Text";
});
```

The following HTML will be properly expanded

```
<span>{{myVar}}</span>
```

to

```
<span>Some Text</span>
```

How do I get the template to accomplish this if I want to store the var name as part of my string instead:

```
app.controller( "myCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.text = "This is quite {{myVar}}";
   $scope.myVar = "Some Text";
});
```

Unfortunately,

```
<span>{{myVar}}</span>
```

becomes

```
<span>This is quite {{myVar}}</span>
```

Is there any easy way to do this in the template?  I've tried using the $interpolate service in the controller, but given that I'm passing scoped objects (from another closure) to the template, $interpolate updates the original object and causes me a problem.  If there was an easy way to return an object by value (instead of by reference) it would solve my problems using $interpolate, but currently I can't figure out how to do that either.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem—or if you even care a year and a half later ;) —, but at first glance [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) appears to quite possibly provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
app.controller( "myCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.myVar = "Some Text";
   $scope.text = "This is quite " + $scope.myVar;
});
```

Demo in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/be374h7fXpY5YZjpe70n?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work.  The `myVar` reference has to be part of the string (coming from another source).  The whole point is that the evaluation has to be done on the string.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the help of directive in this case. The trick is to use $compile service in this case.

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/36KS24zz8flEpTJlsJSH?p=preview) for the same.

Directive code:

```
app.directive('renderText',function($compile){
  var linker = function(scope,element,attr){
    var template = scope.item;
    scope.$watch('template',function(){
                element.html(template);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }); 
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link:linker,
    scope: { 
             item:'=item',
             myVar: '=replace'
            }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around it all and how it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `angular.copy` to create a local copy of `$scope.text` such that any changes to it through the $interpolate service does not affect my original object.